# Loading HTML Page into Body

Tags: c#, razor

Why doesn't this work?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Website Account Manager";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
@{
    System.IO.StreamReader myreader = new System.IO.StreamReader("../htdocs/websiteaccounts/Views/Home/index.htm");
    myreader.ReadToEnd();
    myreader.Close();
}
</p>
```

I just want the index.htm file to show in the body of my cshtml file above, but it doesn't show in the body.  Everything else loads fine, just that problem there.

Comment: Do you get any error messages showing on either the client side or the server logs? Or just a blank page with no errors on either side?

Comment: I am not familiar with `razor`, but in normal `ASP.NET` I believe throwing the `runat="server"` attribute into the `<p>` tag might help. :P

Comment: No error messages at all, just a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    System.IO.StreamReader myreader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path +  "MyTest\\randerhtml.html");
    string s = myreader.ReadToEnd();
    myreader.Close();
    @(new HtmlString(s))
```